# SQL time comparision

Tags: sql, time, compare

I'm trying to show rows which have hour value (24H format) after current time.
Currently I'm using:

```
where time(hour)>time(now())
```

but this comparision fails when current time is for example 23:50 and stored value is 00:10.

Is there any way to copmare it correctly?

This is the part of query to show nearest departures of buses on bus stop.

Comment: By this definition, isn't the logic ALWAYS true?

Comment: Do your departures vary by day?  That is, do you have different schedules for the weekend (the buses around here have different Saturday/Sunday/Holiday schedules)?  If so, you're going to have to add it to the given day, or you may get some really odd departure times...

Comment: Yes it's always true (if it's on the same day), but time of departures are stored chronologicaly, so my query shows the first row that matches that comparision.

They vary, but they are divided into weekdays, Saturdays and Sundays. Weekdays aren't distinguished, so it won't do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could try:

```
where time(hour)>time(now()) or time(hour) = 0
```

Comment: That adds every departure at 00:00 to the results.

Comment: Yes, because midnight is after every other hour in the day.

Comment: Indeed this works :) First time I've just copy/paste it and it didn't work, but after your reply i analyzed it and put 
time(now()) or time(hour) = 0
in brackets and it works perfect

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better if you check if it's in future first, and then check the difference. As far as I understand, that would works better for your usage:

```
WHERE time > NOW() and TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,time,NOW()) < 60
```

Comment: Good idea, this should solve my problem, but it doesn't return any record at all. I'm trying now to figure out why.